# How to format a number to money format in javascript

Tags: javascript, format, number-formatting

I have a number and I want to put into money format, brasilian money. I usually use format like this:

```
that.totalSales = numeral(that.totalSales).format("$ 0,0.00");
```

but that returns a string and I want it to return a number so I can build a chart with chart.js.
Itried to use toLocaleString('pt-BR'), but a value that was to return 9.990.220,32, that returns 9.99.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format numbers as currency string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-to-format-numbers-as-currency-string)

Comment: Anything starting with a currency sign (e.g. "$") will be a string, and can not (easily) be coerced into a number. Why not just use the value of `that.totalSales` *before* you alter it, which is apparently a number?

Comment: it is a number, but a really big number kkkkk, it's 11786775.13, and I need to show as money like 11.786.775,13

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function which does that, it can probably be written much shorter and better but this is what I came up with:

```
const formatNumber = (number, decimals = 2, floatSeparator = '.', separator = ',') => {
    let stringified = number.toString();
    let [ decimal, float ] = stringified.split('.');
    let result = "";
    if(decimal.length > 3) {
        decimal = decimal.split("").reverse();
        for(let i = 0; i < decimal.length; i++) {
            result += decimal[i];
            if((i + 1)%3 === 0 && i !== decimal.length - 1) {
                result += separator;
            }
        }
    }
    result = result.split("").reverse().join("");
    if(float) {
        result += floatSeparator;
        if(float.length >= decimals) {
            for(let i = 0; i < decimals; i++) {
                result += float[i];
            }
        }
        else {
            for(let i = 0; i < decimals; i++) {
                if(i < float.length) {
                    result += float[i];
                }
                else {
                    result += '0';
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

let n1 = 1000;
let n2 = 1000.5;

console.log(formatNumber(n1)); // 1,000
console.log(formatNumber(n2)); // 1,000.50
```

Comment: @GustavoOliveira if this answers your question pleas mark it

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the [number-to-currency](https://www.npmjs.com/package/number-to-currency) package on npm which convert number to currency string with one command.

**How to use:**

install first through npm or yarn: *npm install number-to-currency*

```
const formatter = require("number-to-currency")

formatter(2000) -> 2,000
```